# Redirect to a given Laravel URL

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a method in Redirect class of laravel where the parameter is a complete url? We all know parameters to these methods are just route name,action, slash,..etc but what I want now is like

```
return Redirect::foo('https://bla.com/?yken=KuQxIVTNRctA69VAL6lYMRo0');
```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Yes, it's

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

return Redirect::to('http://heera.it');
```

[**Check the documentation.**](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#redirects)

**Update:** `Redirect::away('url')` (For external link, Laravel Version 4.19):

```
public function away($path, $status = 302, $headers = array())
{
    return $this->createRedirect($path, $status, $headers);
}
```

Comment: The `::to` method is for any url redirect.

Comment: @SheikhHeera Where in the documentation does it explain `::to` accepts absolute URLs? As far as I can see, the examples are all routes and actions?

Comment: I can't find it in the documentation either, but I can confirm that it works with my version of Laravel.

Answer (score 26):

You can use different types of redirect method in laravel -

```
return redirect()->intended('http://heera.it');
```

OR

```
return redirect()->to('http://heera.it');
```

OR

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

return Redirect::to('/')->with(['type' => 'error','message' => 'Your message'])->withInput(Input::except('password'));
```

OR

```
return redirect('/')->with(Auth::logout());
```

OR

```
return redirect()->route('user.profile', ['step' => $step, 'id' => $id]);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `redirect()` method like this:-

```
return redirect('https://stackoverflow.com/');
```

Answer (score 4):

Both `Redirect::to()` and `Redirect::away()` should work.

> Difference
>
> Redirect::to() does additional URL checks and generations. Those
>   additional steps are done in Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator and do
>   the following, if the passed URL is not a fully valid URL (even with
>   protocol):
>
> ```
> Determines if URL is secure
> rawurlencode() the URL
> trim() URL
> ```

src : https://medium.com/@zwacky/laravel-redirect-to-vs-redirect-away-dd875579951f

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in Laravel 5.8

```
return \Redirect::to('https://bla.com/?yken=KuQxIVTNRctA69VAL6lYMRo0');
```

Or instead of / you can use

```
use Redirect;
```

Answer (score -1):

we can use in the latest Laravel version

```
return redirect()->away('https://www.google.com');
```

---

if want to pass **query param:**

```
  $redirectUrl = $request->redirect_url.'/reset-password?token='.$request->token.'&email='.$request->email;

 return redirect()->away($redirectUrl);
```

Comment: This is not how to build a URL with query string parameters. It will break if certain characters are included in the variables. Also, `away()` method was already mentioned in an answer from 2014.