# Laravel 5 - Redirect inside routes.php

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, routes

I'm working in a project with Multi Languages URLs like:

```
mydomain/en/.....
mydomain/fr/.....
```

I'm trying to change my `routes.php` to identify the language and setLocale based on given code, this part is fine, but if the given URL doesn't have the code like `//mydomain/home` I want to redirect to `//mydomain/en/home` using the default locale, or if URL is `//mydomain/` redirect to `//mydomain/en`.

For this I wrote the code:

```
$locale = Request::segment(1);
$languages = Language::getLanguages(array("enabled"=>1));
if (in_array($locale, \Language::$available_locales)) {
    \App::setLocale($locale);
} else {
    \Redirect::to("//mydomain/".Config::get("lang.default_locale"));
}

Route::group(array('prefix' => $locale), function()
{
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return "test";
    });
});
```

The Redirect is not working properly, anyone knows how to use the Redirect inside the `routes.php`?

*The code above is just an example.*

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong here as I am not sure how much ordinary php you might be able to use, but you might be able to do something with the php function `header()`

instead of

```
    \Redirect::to("//mydomain/".Config::get("lang.default_locale"));
```

Perhaps:

```
    $header_info = Config::get("lang.default_locale");
    header("Location: //mydomain/$header_info");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

The backslash could be causing `Redirect` to fail? Sorry I only really do php but saw this had no answer.

Looks like that might be it...no \ before `Redirect` in this script:

[Laravel 4: Redirect to a given url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626492/laravel-4-redirect-to-a-given-url)

Comment: Hi Steve, yes I can do it, but I'm looking for how to use the Laravel objects, but if I don't find I'll do like you mention, Thanks.

Comment: Is the backslash causing Redirect to fail? Sorry I only really do php but saw this had no answer.

Comment: Try removing `".` before `Config::get(....`  and possibly                       `Redirect::to("//mydomain/Config::get('lang.default_locale')")` I think something like that might work in ordinary php so might be the same in Laravel

Comment: I already try this, when I call the redirect function inside the routes.php nothing happens, if I use the same function in the controller works, I'll try to move this code to the base controller and after I'll find a better solution. Thanks Steve

Comment: Does it work with a hard coded url for test purposes? If so you could do the same as the header() example above where you `get` into a variable first.

Comment: The upvote was for sheer persistence - it looks like you are not alone in trying to get that to work judging by the linked questions.