# laravel redirect to a new tab

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I need to open a new URL after a post request. I have done this at the end of my controller.

```
Redirect::away($url)
```

The above calls works perfect, however, I want to **open the URL in a new tab**.

I tried to, away, and intended methods that are there in the laravel doc. None work as intended.

Comment: I think there is no server side way to open a new tab on client side. You will need to do it with JavaScript.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Redirect::away()` or `Redirect:to()` both are server side commands and all they do is to redirect to a url with a slight difference as mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626492/laravel-4-redirect-to-a-given-url)

As, both are server side commands they cannot open a new tab.

You need client side code to open new tab, for example:
`<a href="#" target="_blank">Open in a new tab</a>`

Comment: Thanks. I'm ok with sticking to the current tab for the moment.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, but for reference you can cause a client redirect to a new window/tab from the server using

```
echo "<script>window.open('".$url."', '_blank')</script>";
```

As a side note, whether this opens the link a new window or new tab is dependent on the browser and browser settings.

Comment: When a century has passed and people created so many tools to go from back to front and vice versa, they did it for scalability and order. When you 'echo' in a framework like Laravel, you just take us back a century.

Comment: But the browser will probably block the popup so i think the only robust way of doing it is from frontend.

Answer (score 4):

Laravel or (PHP in general) is a server side and we cannot open a new tab in them, because the new tab is browser thing so the solution is to do it in front side like:

- using `<a>` TAG `<a href="#Link" target="_blank">New tab</a>`.
- using **popup** javascript
  `window.open("Link", "_blank", "scrollbars=yes,width=400,height=400");`
  but you should to be careful here when using it, if you open the window without user interaction the browser probably will block your popup (button click for example is great way to open the popup).

i'm prefer the second method when the window should appear as popup here a full example as  quick use code:

```js
      function show_my_receipt() {
         
         // open the page as popup //
         var page = 'http://www.test.com';
         var myWindow = window.open(page, "_blank", "scrollbars=yes,width=400,height=500,top=300");
         
         // focus on the popup //
         myWindow.focus();
         
         // if you want to close it after some time (like for example open the popup print the receipt and close it) //
         
        //  setTimeout(function() {
        //    myWindow.close();
        //  }, 1000);
        
       }
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="show_my_receipt()">show the receipt</button>
```