# How to open PDF view page in new tab in laravel 5 using controller code?

Tags: pdf, laravel-5

Actually i want to open a pdf page in new tab when we save data of user,but that page where we submit the form , redirect to same page.

```
public function store(Request $request) {

        $user = new UserDetail([
            'full_name' => $request->get('full_name'),
            'street_address' => $request->get('street_address'),
            'city' => $request->get('city'),
            'zip_code' => $request->get('zip_code'),
        ]);

        $user->save();
        $user = UserDetail::find($user->id);

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf', compact('user'));
        //return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
        return Redirect::away($pdf->download('invoice.pdf'));
        //return redirect('/index');
    }
```

any one help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the code below in your view file to open it in a new tab.

```
<a href="{{route("pdfStream")}}" target="_blank" > click me to pdf </a>
```

And in your Controller you can use:

```
public function pdfStream(Request $request){
  $user = UserDetail::find($user->id);
  $data["info"] = $user;
  $pdf = PDF::loadView('whateveryourviewname', $data);
  return $pdf->stream('whateveryourviewname.pdf');
}
```

And your Route:

```
Route::get('/pdf', 'YourController@pdfStream')->name('pdfStream');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Nibir, but thats not my requirement. Open new tab through Controller code  not through <a></a> tag

Comment: But Redirect::away() or Redirect:to() both are server side commands and all they do is to redirect to a url with a slight difference as mentioned in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913461/laravel-redirect-to-a-new-tab
As, both are server side commands they cannot open a new tab.

Comment: Ohh Thanks Dear