# How I can stream pdf files instead of downloading in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, pdf, pdf-generation, dompdf

I currently using **barryvdh/laravel-dompdf** for printing pdf. But whenever I click on the print button it always downloads the file instead of opening a browser tab. How I can fix this ??? **I've seen others post but I didn't get the right solution too.**

```
$customer = Customer::findOrFail($id);
$pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.info-print', $customer);
return $pdf->stream('info.pdf');
```

Comment: I found one solution, Did you try this one?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50416373/15579763

Comment: Tried this but not working ! ! !.

Answer (score 1):

may try this

```
return $pdf->stream('info.pdf', array("Attachment" => false));
```